# Adding tags to Sharepoint online Office 365 documents via C# and CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, document

I have a small project that requires migrating from *Sharepoint 2010* to *Sharepoint Online*. According to Microsoft, tags have been discontinued.

I have been able to add *Enterprise Keywords* and *custom metadata columns* which works great.

Sharepoint Online still has a column for tags (despite it not being editable). The client is still very much focused on tags for the moment. I cannot seem to figure out how to assign a tag via C#. Is there anyone who could point me in the right direction?

```
using (var cc = new OfficeDevPnP
    .Core
    .AuthenticationManager()
    .GetSharePointOnlineAuthenticatedContextTenant(
        "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/", 
        "Test@test.com", 
        "password")) 
    {
        Web web = cc.Web;

        FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
        newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Test\Upload.jpg");
        newFile.Url = "Upload.jpg";

        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List docs 
            = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");

        Folder folder = docs.RootFolder.Folders.GetByUrl("General");
        File uploadFile = folder.Files.Add(newFile);

        //uploadFile.Tag = ???

        cc.Load(docs);
        cc.Load(uploadFile);
        cc.ExecuteQuery(); 
    }
```

What do I set at `uploadFile.Tag`?